# SQL Server : multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need a simple output of fields named "36" - "1" with the extended inventory value for everything in the specified item classes. I don't need itemization.

E.g.

[image]

Error is:

"Database Connector Error. '42000:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "InvenFiscPerHistTable.FiscalPeriod" could no be bound. [Database Vendor Code: 4104 ]'

Here's my SQL.

```
DECLARE @CalMonth INT
DECLARE @CalYear INT
DECLARE @CalMoYear DATETIME

SET @CalMonth = CASE WHEN "InvenFiscPerHistTable"."FiscalPeriod" IN (1,2,3) THEN "InvenFiscPerHistTable"."FiscalPeriod" + 9 ELSE "InvenFiscPerHistTable"."FiscalPeriod" - 3 END
SET @CalYear = CASE WHEN "InvenFiscPerHistTable"."FiscalPeriod" IN (1,2,3) THEN "InvenFiscPerHistTable"."FiscalYear" + 1 ELSE "InvenFiscPerHistTable"."FiscalYear" END
SET @CalMoYear = CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @CalYear) + '-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @CalMonth) + '-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,1) AS DATETIME)
--our fiscal year is not the same as the calendar year
--e.g. FiscalPeriod = 1 and FiscalYear = 2016 will be October 2015

SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN @CalMoYear BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -36, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -35, GETDATE()-day (GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN"InvenFiscPerHistTable"."QOH" * "InvenTable"."UnitCost"  ELSE NULL END) AS "36"
,SUM (CASE WHEN @CalMoYear BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -35, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -34, GETDATE()-day (GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN"InvenFiscPerHistTable"."QOH" * "InvenTable"."UnitCost"  ELSE NULL END) AS "35"
,SUM (CASE WHEN @CalMoYear BETWEEN DATEADD(m, -34, GETDATE()-day(GETDATE()-1)) AND DATEADD(m, -33, GETDATE()-day (GETDATE()-1))-1 THEN"InvenFiscPerHistTable"."QOH" * "InvenTable"."UnitCost"  ELSE NULL END) AS "34"
--and so on until I have 36 months of history up through last month

FROM "InvenTable" 
INNER JOIN "SKUTable" ON "InvenTable"."SKUKey" = "SKUTable"."SKUKey"
INNER JOIN "InvenFiscPerHistTable" ON ("InvenTable"."SKUKey" = "InvenFiscPerHistTable"."SKUKey")
    AND ("InvenTable"."WarehouseKey" = "InvenFiscPerHistTable"."WarehouseKey")

INNER JOIN "SKUClassTable" "SKUClassTable" ON "SKUTable"."ICKey" = "SKUClassTable"."ICKey"
WHERE "SKUClassTable"."ItemClassName" IN (
    '105-03'
    ,'105-04'
    ,'105-05'
    ,'105-06'
    ,'150-01'
    )
```

Comment: Is there a table here called "timInvtFiskPerHist"?  I'm not seeing it in your SQL.

Comment: @AdamMiller I edited the question

Comment: Why do you have double quotes around all your schemas and objects? They should either be removed or replaced with [ ]. What happens when you run this in SSMS?

Comment: @SeanLange because that's how Crystal Reports formats SQL. Unconventional, I suppose, but I'm working with what I have.

Comment: I appreciate the critiques of my question; I really do. Anybody wanna take a run at answering it? I know I'm hopelessly naive, but I'm sure this is far from the most complicated SQL question ever posted here.

Comment: @SOSteppenwolf Is the columns meant to hold values from that month? (Like 36 = August 2012). If so your date calculations seem to be off a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around a bit with your query and think it can be rewritten and simplified (in my opinion) to the query below. The only thing you need to do is add more items in the pivot part at the end to get more columns.

The logic is that it calculates the difference in months between the first day of the current month and the date that is created from the FiscalYear and FiscalPeriod (according to your rules).

I believe it should work, unless I missed something vital, but without any test data there's of course a fair amount of guess work involved ;-)

Please give it a try and if it doesn't work I'll remove my answer.

I formatted it a bit less compact than it could be to make it easier to follow.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT 
    SKUKey, WarehouseKey, FiscalPeriod, FiscalYear, QOH,
    diff = DATEDIFF
           (
            month,
            CASE WHEN FiscalPeriod IN (1,2,3) 
                 THEN 
                     CAST(FiscalYear + 1 AS CHAR(4))
                     + '-' + CAST(FiscalPeriod + 9 AS VARCHAR(2))
                     + '-' + CAST(1 AS CHAR(1))
                 ELSE 
                     CAST(FiscalYear AS CHAR(4))
                     + '-' + CAST(FiscalPeriod - 3 AS VARCHAR(2))
                     + '-' + CAST(1 AS CHAR(1))
            END,  
            DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
           )
  FROM InvenFiscPerHistTable
)

SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT diff, QOH * UnitCost as TotalCost
    FROM InvenTable i
    INNER JOIN SKUTable s ON i.SKUKey = s.SKUKey
    INNER JOIN cte ON (i.SKUKey = cte.SKUKey) AND (i.WarehouseKey = cte.WarehouseKey)
    INNER JOIN SKUClassTable sc ON s.ICKey = sc.ICKey
    WHERE sc.ItemClassName IN ('105-03','105-04','105-05','105-06','150-01')
) A
PIVOT ( SUM(TotalCost) FOR diff IN ([36],[35],[2],[1]) ) p -- add more columns here
```